# Delphi throwing error "undeclared identifier TForm", why?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, vcl

I have been facing this error for like 30 mins and I can't find a solution. Can someone please help me?

[image: Error line in Delphi IDE]

[image: var line in Delphi IDE]

I tried to google for a solution, but I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TForm` is declared in the VCL's `Forms` unit, which is missing in the `uses` clause of your unit's `interface` section.  That is why you are getting an error about `TForm` being undeclared.

Fixing that should solve the errors about `Perform()` and `Close()`, too.

Regarding the other "undeclared identifier" errors:

- `clWindow` is declared in the `Graphics` unit.
- `FormatDateTime()`, `Now()`, and `DateToStr()` are declared in the `SysUtils` unit.
- `MessageDlg()` is declared in the `Dialogs` unit.

Make sure those units are in your `uses` clause as well, preferably in your unit's `implementation` section rather than in its `interface` section.

Comment: That project is old one month, compiled, working and added to ZIP archive because I had to reinstall OS. Now, trying to fix some bugs and build again and errors appear. I every form.

Comment: @AckeeXZ all I can tell you is what I see in the images you provided. The `Forms` unit must be in the `uses` clause of the `interface` section in order for the `TformaZaduzenje = class(TForm)` statement to compile properly.  But `Forms` is missing in the image you provided.

Comment: Yup, fixed! Thank you so much! <3

Comment: note: it is discouraged to answer questions with significant content problems. See [/help/how-to-answer](/help/how-to-answer) and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541

Comment: @AckeeXZ Better use a SCM independant from your dev machine